# Microsoft Access - Improving Performance of Large Joins

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables (approximately 20,000 rows each and 5-7 columns) that I need to perform a join operation on. Currently this is being done using:

```
SELECT * INTO Output FROM
ConditionTable LEFT JOIN TagsTable
ON ConditionTable.Condition LIKE '*'&TagsTable.Tag&'*'
```

I need to join the TagsTable onto the ConditionTable wherever the value in the Tag column is found within the value in Condition column.

Both fields are text fields. The Tag field is approximately 20 characters or so. The condition field can be longer, up to 200 characters or so. Neither field is unique.

Currently this takes a long time to execute - around 45 min.

These tables are only going to get bigger so I am looking for ideas on how this could be improved, done faster or alternative methods.

Thanks!

Comment: You're never going to improve the performance of any query that uses `LIKE` with a leading wildcard. The presence of the wildcard means that every single row in the table must be scanned to see if the portion after the wildcard can be matched, which is made worse by using a large-scope wildcard that can include a large portion of the column text, meaning that no index can be used. Poor table design results in poor performance.

Comment: Because your join condition is not '=', and the wildcard search is not limited to the trailing part of the Condition (i.e. the tag can occur anywhere in Condition), an index will not help, this is  a 20Kx20K 400 million comparison operations. I will take long. You might consider creating a 'match' table, and keep updating it as your data in both tables change, incrementally.

Comment: Above is correct. If you can remove the leading * (wild card), then indexing can be used, and the query will take a fraction of the time. But with a wild card on both sides of the expression - you doing a text scan match, and every single row in that table will have to be tested.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. What sort of performance should be expected with indexing? I have tried splitting the condition column by " " delimiter into rows, and then removing the leading '*' from the join condition (I probably didn't describe well enough above that this exercise is like finding specific words in sentences not characters in text strings). This is still taking quite some time to execute. I have changed the properties of both the Tag field and Condition field to be Indexed. Thanks again

Comment: Indexing is analogous to using a book index to find a page containing a word. Without one, a search is much less efficient. Given your situation, @userMT's suggestion of a Match table (e.g., TagsToConditions) sounds like a great approach.

Answer (score 0):

SQL server has what is called free text indexing. Access does not.

However, what this means? Well, at the most basic level, you would need to normalize your data into "atomic" or so called individual values.

So, I might have say my animals table like this:

ID: autonumber
Animal:

So I might then have this:

1: dog
2: cat
3: bird

so, that is our table of tags, and the Animal column is indexed.

Now, we might have say this table:

tblPeople: Firstname, Lastname and then say a long text column - maybe even memo called story:

In that big paragraph we might have say a child hood story, but we want to match out animals from that big chunk of text.

As noted, if you have SQL server, then you can create a "keyword" or so called free text indexing, and you can match/scan against such text column - and they are automatic broken down into a key words and index (each induvial word in the text paragraph is indexed for you.

So, what to do?

You would need to write some code on save of the one record on the form, and SPLIT OUT the text memo paragraph into separate words, and then save those to a child table.

So, we have tblpeople, and tblPeopleKeyWords.

In the after update event of the form save of the one record, then we would have code to take that text column/paragraph, and write out key words to the child table (tblPoepleKeyWords). The code is not hard. But before you attempt this, you might wall be able to say use Access, but adopt SQL server (even the free edition) as the database. (so the feature would be built in, and no code required).

However, assuming we don't have SQL server? Then the code to write out that text as keywords would look like this:

[image]

So, in above, we want to index "my story"

In the forms before update event? Well, we now this this setup:

[image]

So, what we will do is take EACH word in the "my story" column (a memo field), and split out each word, and then write out to our key words table.

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
 
  ' builld key words table
  
  If Me.MyStory.OldValue = Me.MyStory Then
     ' no change - exit - no need to re-index
     Debug.Print "no change - no re-index"
     Exit Sub
  End If
        
  Dim sBuf As String
  
  sBuf = Me.MyStory
  
  sBuf = Replace(sBuf, ",", " ")      ' remove ,
  sBuf = Replace(sBuf, vbCrLf, " ")   ' remove each new line (if user hits enter key)
  
  sBuf = Replace(sBuf, "  ", " ")     ' change all double spaces to one
     

  ' VERY tricky code to maintain the key list - so, just delete then all!!!!
  
  CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE * FROM tblPeopleKeys WHERE People_ID = " & Me!ID
  
  Dim MyKeys() As String
  
  MyKeys = Split(sBuf, " ")
  Dim sKey As Variant
  
  Dim rstKeys       As DAO.Recordset
  Set rstKeys = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblPeopleKeys")
  
  
  For Each sKey In MyKeys
  
     If sKey <> "" Then
        rstKeys.AddNew
        rstKeys!People_ID = Me!ID
        rstKeys!KeyWord = sKey
        rstKeys.Update
     End If
     
  Next
     
  rstKeys.Close
  

End Sub
```

We now can join on that other table - this will perform instant - even with 50,000, or 100,000 rows. And thus you can find any keyword in that text, and event join against that table. After we run above, you in fact see this:

[image]

So, in effect, this gives you the sql server like "key word", or so called free text indexing of that text - and you can now join, or search for any keyword against that child table of keywords.